# Direct link to Buddypress change username : concatenation issue

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation, buddypress

I am trying to create a direct php link to enable users to change their username on Buddypress (Wordpress)

I managed to make a link to the user profile like this :

```
<?php echo'<a href="' . bp_loggedin_user_domain() . '">Users Area</a>'; ?>
```

It works, now I just want to append to that url /settings/change-username/, so that it gives something like : 
http://mywebsite.com/members/nameofthemember/settings/change-username/

I tried loooooooooots of combinations with concatenation, but none of them works, that's why I'm asking for your help now.

A few exemples of what I've tried :

```
<?php echo '<a href="' . bp_loggedin_user_domain() . '/settings/change-username/'">Users Area</a>'; ?>

<?php echo '<a href="' . bp_loggedin_user_domain() . /settings/change-username/'">Users Area</a>'; ?>

<?php echo '<a href="' . bp_loggedin_user_domain() . ' . /settings/change-username/ . '">Users Area</a>'; ?>

<?php echo '<a href="' . bp_loggedin_user_domain() . ' . '/settings/change-username/'">Users Area</a>'; ?>
```

etc.

What's the correct syntax please ?  :)

Comment: I meant "Buddypress" in the question title sorry :)

Comment: What language is this? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Done ! I added some other tags